# Subsets of $A$ with finite measure where $\mu(A)=+\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following lemma:

> Let $(\sigma,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measurable space that satisfies the following:
>
> > If $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mu(A)=+\infty$, then, $\exists\  B \subseteq A$ such that $B \in \mathcal{F}$ and $0<\mu(B)<+\infty$.
> > So, if $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then, for any $r>0$, $\exists\ B\subseteq A$ such that $B \in \mathcal{F}$ and $r<\mu(B)<+\infty$.

I did some thinking about and found a proof, however, I am not very convinced about an specific argument. The right part of the inequality is clear from the hypothesis. In order to prove that $\mu(B)>r$, I took a sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathcal{F}$, where $A_n \downarrow \emptyset$, with $\mu(A_n) < +\infty$ only when $n\geq N_0$ for a fixed $N_0>0$.

From monotonicity, we have that $\mu(A_n)<+\infty$ and $\mu(A_{N_0})<\mu(A_{N_0+1})<...<\mu(A_{n'})<...<\mu(\emptyset)=0$ so, it must have $n'>N_0$ such that $\mu(A_{N_0})<\mu(A_{n'})<\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and, since $r$ is in the "middle" of this sequence, we could have $\mu(A_{n'})=r$.

This last paragraph is, exactly, what I am not certain, because it seems that I've assumed $\mu(A_{N_0})>r$, which is exactly what should be prooved.

Could anyone give me a hand or another way to prove it?

Comment: Could you describe the sequence $\{A_n\}_n$ in more detail?

Comment: It is just a sequence of sets where $A_n \supset A_{n+1}$, which decreases to the empty set.

Comment: Then how do you prevent it from being almost always equal to the empty set and otherwise equal to, say, $A$?

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative, and perhaps more direct way to study this. Suppose $\mu(A)=\infty$. Define $\alpha:=\sup\{\mu(B): 0<\mu(B)<\infty, \, B\subset A\}$. There is a monotone increasing sequence $B_n$ of subsets of $A$ that have positive finite measure and such that $\lim_n\mu(B_n)=\alpha$. Then,  $\mu(B)=\mu(\bigcup_nB_n)=\lim_n\mu(B_n)=\alpha$.

If $\alpha<\infty$, then $\mu(A\setminus B)=\infty$ and so, there is $E\subset A\setminus B$ with $0<\mu(E)<\infty$. This means that $\alpha=\mu(B)<\mu(B\cup E)=\mu(B)+\mu(E)<\infty$ in contradiction to the definition of $\alpha$. Hence $\alpha=\infty$, and the statement of the OP follows.